# Lucene BigDecimal Range Query

Tags: hibernate, lucene, bigdecimal, hibernate-search

I have the following field defined on my entity class:

```
@Column
@FieldBridge(impl = BigDecimalNumericFieldBridge.class)
@Fields(
  @Field(),
  @Field(name = "test_sort", analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO, index = Index.NO))
@NumericField
@SortableField(forField = "test_sort")
val test: BigDecimal
```

My BigDecimalNumericFieldBridge class uses the implementation described in the docs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-custom-numericfieldbridge and in the forums here: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/sorting-on-bigdecimal-field/2339

I'm using a custom query parser to convert the query to a numeric range query like so:

```
override fun newRangeQuery(field: String, part1: String, part2: String, startInclusive: Boolean, endInclusive: Boolean) {
  if ("test" == field) {
    val convertedPart1 = BigDecimal(part1).multiply(storeFactor).longValueExact()
    val convertedPart2 = BigDecimal(part2).multiply(storeFactor).longValueExact()
    return NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange(field, convertedPart1, convertedPart2, startInclusive, endInclusive)
  }

  return super.newRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, startInclusive, endInclusive)
}
```

All of the queries I do on this field return zero results even if I do a range from 0 to 999999999999 which I know includes all values. If I leave it as a string search I get the following error: "contains a string based sub query which targets the numeric field". Sorting on the field works. What am I missing? Thank you in advance for the help.

**Edit**
Adding the field bridge logic:

```
class BigDecimalNumericFieldBridge : TwoWayFieldBridge {

  override fun get(name: String, document: Document): Any? {
    val fromLucene: String = document.get(name) ?: ""

    if (fromLucene.isNotBlank()) {
      return fromLucene.toBigDecimal().divide(LUCENE_BIG_DECIMAL_STORE_FACTOR)
    }

    return null
  }

  override fun set(name: String, value: Any?, document: Document, options: LuceneOptions) {
    if (value != null && name == "test_sort") {
      val decimalValue: BigDecimal = value as BigDecimal
      val indexedValue: Long = decimalValue
          .multiply(LUCENE_BIG_DECIMAL_STORE_FACTOR)
          .longValueExact()
      options.addNumericFieldToDocument(name, indexedValue, document)
      options.addNumericDocValuesFieldToDocument(name, indexedValue, document)
    }
  }

  override fun objectToString(obj: Any?): String {
    return obj.toString()
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact code of your bridge. Did you apply [my suggestion](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/sorting-on-bigdecimal-field/2339/2?u=yrodiere) which is marked as a solution in the forum thread you linked? You need docvalues in order for range queries to work on numeric fields.

Comment: Posted the field bridge and yes I used your suggestion and also applied the ```addNumericDocValuesToDocument``` method. As I posted the bridge logic, I'm wondering if my issue is because I'm only adding values when the field is ```test_sort``` not ```test```. Should I be adding both fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding both fields in the `set` function of the field bridge logic fixes the problem:

```
if (value != null && (name == "test" || name == "test_sort")) {
```

Now my searches work. I guess that makes me wonder if I need the two separate field definitions. I think I could get away with just the one `@Field` annotation and then I wouldn't need to store both `test` and `test_sort`.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding both fields in the set function of the field bridge logic fixes the problem
>   Now my searches work. I guess that makes me wonder if I need the two separate field definitions. I think I could get away with just the one @Field annotation and then I wouldn't need to store both test and test_sort.

You are probably referencing field `test` in your sort. If your sort field is named `test_sort`, you must use that name when creating the sort in your search query.